# React ChakraUI ForwardRef child ignoring variant prop

Tags: css, reactjs, react-props, chakra-ui

I'm having an issue with [forwardRef](https://chakra-ui.com/guides/as-prop#option-1-using-forwardref-from-chakra-uireact) and [Input](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/form/input) from ChakraUI.

I tried to do a generic input component which has always flushed variant. My problem is Chakra does reset variant to default.

**ModalInput Component**

```
import { forwardRef, InputProps, Input } from '@chakra-ui/react';

const ModalInput = forwardRef<InputProps, 'input'>((props, ref) => (
    <Input ref={ref} color="gray.600" variant="flushed" {...props}>
        {props.children}
    </Input>
));

export default ModalInput;
```

**ModalInput Component**

```
<ModalInput placeholder="ex: Entreprise Dupont" />
```

This way, all my `ModalInput` should have variant flushed, but you can see on the screenshot below it is outline.

[image: screenshot outline]

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered this bug was due to `InputGroup`, which was enclosing my `ModalInput`.

Reported this bug [here](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/5103).
Find the sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/chakra-ui-forked-t9q2s)